# Amazon & HTML AgiltiyPack

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

It seems almost all of my request are being hit with an 500 SERVICE ERROR.

Yet I am able to access the site through a web browser just fine.I am sending UserAgent through HAP as well.

Is there anyone with experince on this matter know how Amazon is detecting that the HAP request is a robot?

```
  Dim aHtml As New HtmlWeb
    Dim UserAgent1 As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11"
    Dim iPadAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10"
    Dim AndroidAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.0; en-us; Xoom Build/HRI39) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13"
    Dim iPhoneAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5"
    Dim ChromeAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11"
    aHtml.UserAgent = iPadAgent

    Dim Credentials As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "", "")

    Dim proxy As New System.Net.WebProxy


    Dim proxyAddress As New Uri("http://11.11.11.11")
    proxy.Address = proxyAddress

    Dim aDoc As HtmlDocument = aHtml.Load(AmazonURL, "GET")

    Dim aNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
    aNode = aDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='olpDivId']/span[2]")

    If aNode.InnerText Is Nothing Then

    End If

    Dim UsedPrice1 As String = aNode.InnerText
    Dim i As Integer = UsedPrice1.IndexOf("$")
    Dim UsedPrice As Integer = UsedPrice1.Substring(i + 1)

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Delay)

    Return UsedPrice
```

'

WebClient Method(Retunrs 503):

```
 Dim filename As String = "amzContent.html"
    Client.Headers("User-Agent") = ChromeAgent
    Client.Proxy = proxy
    Client.Credentials = Credentials
    Client.DownloadFile(AmazonURL, (Server.MapPath("amz//") & _
                  filename))
    Dim aDoc As HtmlDocument = aHtml.Load(Server.MapPath("amz//") & _
                  filename)
```

Comment: Odd, the `System.Net.WebClient` can read the page just fine. Might be a problem in HAP... Even stranger, I'm able to read from HAP just fine biw.  Maybe they're having problems on their end?...  It seems so, downloading multiple times randomly works.

Comment: You experienced the same results with HAP?

Comment: Yeah, just hitting `http://www.amazon.com` through HAP repeatedly either 500's or every once in a while loads the HTML fine. Using `System.Net.WebClient` loads fine consistently.

Comment: I am getting 503 using WebClient

Answer (score 0):

**Using the WebClient Method above, and sending language,charset,and accept headers seems to work for now**